# VBA Excel, how do i insert a formula into a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a table with headers via VBA,

Header: 
[Name][ID][Check]

on a different cell, i want to calculate the amount of "Checks" summed up.

So i tried to do this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Formula = "=SUM(" & shortname & "[[#All];[Check]])"
```

When i run the code i get error 1004,  and when i look it up,
it says it is possible that it is ambigious, but there is only one coumn named Check.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using **,** rather than **;**

Comment: OMG,,  yes,,   in my country ; are used in the spread sheets, but ofcurse i need to use ,  in VBA.   haha..

Thank you so much..   Can you submit as answer..  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use .Formula, syntax and (names of) functions must follow the US standard.
Otherwise use .FormulaLocal.